# Piece-wise Linear Function from a Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, linear-interpolation, piecewise

I have a many large Pandas series of "cost slopes" representing a linear function `f` given in an painful form.  Here is a much smaller example:

```
slopes = Series({'-inf': 10, -200: 60, 0: 0, 200: 1, 'inf': 10})

-inf    10
-200    60
0        0
200      1
inf     10
```

(0, 0) is always in the Series, and the slopes represent the piecewise "marginal cost" as you move from zero either direction

```
f(-200) = 12000  # abs(-200) * 60
f(-100) = 6000  # abs(-100) * 60
f(0) = 0
f(100) = 100  # 100 * 1
f(200) = 200  # 200 * 1
f(300) = 1200  # 200 * 1 + (300-200) * 10
```

as the series are large and are called many times I was hoping to put this in a form where I can use Numpy's `interp` or `piecewise` or Pandas `interpolate` for speed rather than building `for` loops.

I think [`piecewise`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html) might be the solution, but I'm not sure how to convert and handle the `inf`?  Maybe there is a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1):

By choosing to use `np.piecewise`, you just have to specify your cost slopes intervals as `condlist` and the corresponding linear function expressions as `funclist` like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([-200,-100,0,100,200,300])

condlist = [x<-200,\
            np.logical_and(x>=-200, x<0),\
            x==0,\
            np.logical_and(x>0,x<=200),\
            x>200]
funclist = [lambda x: 200*60+abs(x+200)*10,\
            lambda x: abs(x)*60,\
            lambda x:0,\
            lambda x: abs(x)*1,\
            lambda x: 200*1+abs(x-200)*10]

f = np.piecewise(x,condlist,funclist)
```

verifying implementation correctness with given points, it follows:

```
np.allclose([12000,6000,0,100,200,1200],f)
>>> True
```

which plotted for a larger range, let's say `x = np.linspace(-500,500,2000)`, finally gives:

```
plt.plot(x, f,'r')
plt.scatter([-200,-100,0,100,200,300],[12000,6000,0,100,200,1200],s=20,zorder=5)
```

[image: piecewise_output]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting, so the inf/-inf seem to be handled reasonably which is useful to know and `piecewise` can possibly the job.  I have no idea how to reasonably turn those many different Series those 'condlist' and 'funclist' programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
slopes = pd.Series({ -math.inf: 10, -200: 60, 0: 0, 200: 1, 300: 10, math.inf: 10})
```

Define your cost function as you wish

```
def cost_func(x):
    if x[0] < 200:
        return abs(x[0]) * x[1]
    else: 
        return 200 + abs(x[0]-200) * x[1]

slope_df = pd.DataFrame({'value':slopes.index, 'amount':slopes.values}, index = range(slopes.size))

slope_df['cost'] = slope_df[ ['value', 'amount'] ].apply(lambda row: cost_func(row), axis=1)
print(slope_df)
```

[image: slope_df output]